# How to change the OpenStreetMap language (or at least the alphabet)

Tags: openstreetmap, internationalization

I just arrived in Belgrade. I am browsing the map in OpenStreeMap.org and in the OSMAnd programme. Everything is in Serbian, street names, points of interest, etc. [Check it by yourself](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/44.8217/20.4530).

The difficulty for me with Serbian is that it is coded in a different alphabet, the Cyrillic. This means that searching for a keyword like "museum" returns no results. Even if I knew how to write "boulevard" or "restaurant" in Cyrillic, I would need a different keyboard in my laptop.

Is there any possibiliy of changing the labelling language in OpenStreetMap? Or at least of changing the alphabet, so that the label `Београд` is displayed as `Beograd`?

Comment: Is this question about the OSM website or OsmAnd? The app OsmAnd lets you choose whether to show labels in the local language or a user defined one.

Comment: You could use overpassturbo and the desired tags to download the data you want and view it in QGis. Not convenient, but it works.

Comment: You can use the Cycle Map tiles (some tags are English) example https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/44.8215/20.4507&layers=C

Comment: @scal My mistake, I thought this would have the same solution on both the web map and the programme. Please insert an answer with the steps to change the map language in OSMAnd.

Answer (score 1):

Most objects have name in cyrillic but they also have name:en tag in english. so my suggestion is to download the data in josm. select all and delete name tag and rename name:en to name. Then you can use [OsmAndMapCreator](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmAndMapCreator) to make obf files which can be used in OSMAND.

Comment: I can not try this right now, but makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

While it's been a while since the question has been asked, it might be worth adding this information.

[This](https://osmand.net/features/start) page shows how to set the Map Language. Any language can be chosen, together with the fallback.

> To change the map names language, please go to Configure map - Map language. You can set it to Local names and the map names will be displayed in the language of the region or you can choose one language for all names. Also, you can choose to transliterate the names if they are missing on the map in your language.

In effect, this will display the name in the selected language, if an appropriate language tag exists. If not, it will use the fallback option.